# Fight against Enemies (RPG in Java)

Tags: java, object-oriented, role-playing-game

I've written a program that simulates a fight between the player and an enemy to gain experience in the programming of such role-playing games. Above all, it was important to me to have good, object-oriented design. Criticism in this regard is expressly desired.

*Explanation of the skills:*

```
Fireball (needs 1 mana) - this is a skill that causes damage on an enemy. Nothing special.
Healing (needs 3 mana) - this skill heals the caster.
Knock Out (needs 2 mana) - this skill knocks the enemy out. He cant cast skills in this or in the next round. He also gets damage.
Poisoning (needs 3 mana) - the enemy gets damage and is poisoned in the next rounds. So he gets damage in the next rounds.
```

Sorry for my bad english. I will improve it :)

[The program can be tested here](https://repl.it/@Dexter1997/StaidRobustUnicorn)

**Here are my source files**

*Game.java*

```
public class Game {
    private Player player;
    private NPC enemy;

    private int score;

    public Game() {
        player = new Player("Player", 20, 5, 5);
        enemy = new NPC("Enemy", 20, 5, 5);
    }

    public boolean fight() {
        UF.println(player.getName() + " fights against " + enemy.getName(), 1000);
        int rounds = 1;

        while(player.getLife() > 0 && enemy.getLife() > 0) {
            UF.println(" --- Round " + rounds + " --- \n", 1000);
            UF.println(player.getName() + " Stats", 0);
            UF.println("Life: " + UF.displayGraphical(player.getLife(), player.getLifeMax(), "#"), 0);
            UF.println("Mana: " + UF.displayGraphical(player.getMana(), player.getManaMax(), "@") + "\n", 1000);
            UF.println(enemy.getName() + " Stats", 0);
            UF.println("Life: " + UF.displayGraphical(enemy.getLife(), enemy.getLifeMax(), "#"), 0);
            UF.println("Mana: " + UF.displayGraphical(enemy.getMana(), enemy.getManaMax(), "@") + "\n", 1000);
            player.isPoisoned();
            if(player.getLife() <= 0) break;
            player.chooseSkill(enemy);
            if(enemy.getLife() <= 0 || player.getLife() <= 0) break;
            enemy.isPoisoned();
            if(enemy.getLife() <= 0) break;
            enemy.chooseSkill(player);
            rounds++;
        }

        if(player.getLife() > 0 && enemy.getLife() <= 0) {
            UF.println("YOU HAVE WON! YOU ARE NOW STRONGER", 2000);
            UF.println("PREPARE FOR THE NEXT FIGHT!\n", 2000);
            score++;
            enemy.getStronger(1.2);
            player.getStronger();
            return true;
        } else {
            UF.println("Game over!", 0);
            UF.println("You reached " + score + " Points. Gratulation!", 2000);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void mainLoop() {
        while(fight());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.mainLoop();
    }
}
```

*UF.java*

```
// name stands for "useful functions"
public class UF {
    public static void println(String text, int time) {
        System.out.println(text);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String displayGraphical(int value1, int value2, String symbol) {
        if(value2 < value1) {
            return "error";
        }

        String text = "[";
        int numberOfSymbols = 0;
        int numberOfWhiteSpace = 20;

        float filledOut = (float)value1 / (float)value2;
        numberOfSymbols = (int)(filledOut * 20);
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSymbols; i++) {
            text += symbol;
        }
        numberOfWhiteSpace -= numberOfSymbols;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfWhiteSpace; i++) {
            text += " ";
        }
        text += "] (" + value1 + " / " + value2 + ")";
        return text;
    }
}
```

*Being.java*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Being {
    // basic values
    private String name;

    protected int lifeMax;
    protected int manaMax;
    protected int powerMax;

    protected int lifeActual;
    protected int manaActual;
    protected int powerActual;

    // skills
    protected Skill fireball;
    protected Skill knockOut;
    protected Skill healing;
    protected Skill poisoning;

    // state values
    protected boolean alive;
    protected boolean isKnockedOut;
    protected int[] isPoisoned;

    public Being(String name, int lifeMax, int manaMax, int powerMax) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lifeMax = lifeMax;
        this.manaMax = manaMax;
        this.powerMax = powerMax;

        this.lifeActual = lifeMax;
        this.manaActual = manaMax;
        this.powerActual = powerMax;

        // skills
        fireball = new Skill(this, "Fireball", 1, 1, 1);
        knockOut = new Skill(this, "Knock Out", 1, 0.5, 2);
        healing = new Skill(this, "Healing", 1, 2, 3);
        poisoning = new Skill(this, "Poisoning", 1, 0.2, 3);

        // state values
        alive = true;
        isKnockedOut = false;
        // how many rounds, how big is damage
        isPoisoned = new int[2];
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        String text = "";
        text += name + "\n";
        text += "Life:  " + lifeActual + " / " + lifeMax + "\n";
        text += "Mana:  " + manaActual + " / " + manaMax + "\n";
        text += "Power: " + powerMax + " / " + powerMax + "\n";
        return text; 
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getLife() {
        return lifeActual;
    }

    public int getLifeMax() {
        return lifeMax;
    }

    public int getMana() {
        return manaActual;
    }

    public int getManaMax() {
        return manaMax;
    }

    public int getPower() {
        return powerActual;
    }

    public boolean isKnockedOut() {
        if(isKnockedOut) {
            UF.println(name + " is knocked out and can't cast skills this round\n", 1000);
            isKnockedOut = false;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void isPoisoned() {
        if(isPoisoned[0] > 0) {
            UF.println(name + " is poisoned", 1000);
            sustainDamage(isPoisoned[1]);
            isPoisoned[0]--;
        }
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return alive;
    }

    public void sustainDamage(int value) {
        if(value > 0) {
            lifeActual -= value;
            UF.println(name + " has gotten " + value + " damage\n", 1000);
        }

        if (lifeActual <= 0) {
            alive = false;
        }
    }

    public boolean useMana(int value) {
        if(value <= manaActual) {
            manaActual -= value;
            UF.println(name + " has used " + value + " mana.", 1000);
            return true;
        } else {
            UF.println(name + " has not enough mana.", 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void cureLife(int value) {
        int difference = lifeMax - lifeActual;
        if(value >= difference) {
            lifeActual = lifeMax;
            UF.println(name + " is fully healed.", 1000);
        } else {
            lifeActual += value;
            UF.println(name + " has healed " + value + " life points.", 1000);
        }
    }

    public void castFireball(Being enemy) {
        UF.println(name + " casts " + fireball.getName() + " on " + enemy.getName() + ".", 1000);
        if(useMana(fireball.getManaRequirement())) {
            enemy.sustainDamage(fireball.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void castHealing() {
        UF.println(name + " casts " + healing.getName() + ".", 1000);
        if(useMana(healing.getManaRequirement())) {
            cureLife(healing.getValue());
        }
    }

    public void castKnockOut(Being enemy) {
        UF.println(name + " casts " + knockOut.getName() + " on " + enemy.getName() + ".", 1000);
        if(useMana(knockOut.getManaRequirement())) {
            enemy.sustainDamage(knockOut.getValue());
            enemy.isKnockedOut = true;
            UF.println(enemy.getName() + " is knocked out.", 1000);
        }
    }

    public void castPoisoning(Being enemy) {
        UF.println(name + " casts " + poisoning.getName() + " on " + enemy.getName() + ".", 1000);
        if(useMana(poisoning.getManaRequirement())) {
            enemy.sustainDamage(powerActual / 2);
            enemy.isPoisoned[0] = poisoning.getLevel() + 2;
            enemy.isPoisoned[1] = poisoning.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

*Player.java*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player extends Being {
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Player(String name, int lifeMax, int manaMax, int powerMax) {
        super(name, lifeMax, manaMax, powerMax);
    }   

    public void chooseSkill(Being enemy) {
        if(!isKnockedOut()) {
            System.out.println("[1] Fireball");
            System.out.println("[2] Healing");
            System.out.println("[3] Knock Out");
            System.out.println("[4] Poisoning");
            System.out.println("[5] Give up");
            System.out.println("[*] Do nothing");
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            String command = input.next();

            if(command.equals("1")) {
                castFireball(enemy);
            } else if (command.equals("2")) {
                castHealing();
            } else if (command.equals("3")) {
                castKnockOut(enemy);
            } else if (command.equals("4")) {
                castPoisoning(enemy);
            } else if (command.equals("5")) {
                lifeActual = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void getStronger() {
        lifeMax += 5;
        manaMax += 2;
        powerMax += 1;

        lifeActual = lifeMax;
        manaActual = manaMax;
        powerActual = powerMax;

        isKnockedOut = false;
        isPoisoned[0] = 0;
        isPoisoned[1] = 0;
    }
}
```

*NPC.java*

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class NPC extends Being {
    public NPC(String name, int lifeMax, int manaMax, int powerMax) {
        super(name, lifeMax, manaMax, powerMax);
    }

    // this is actually my first KI, i am so proud
    public void chooseSkill(Being enemy) {
        if(isKnockedOut()) {
            return;
        }

        if (manaActual == 0) {
            lifeActual = 0;
            UF.println(getName() + " gives up because he has no mana.", 1000);
            return;
        }

        // decide for a skill
        int decision;
        while(true) {
            decision = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 4);

            // i hope this is an accepted style, but i suspect it isnt
            if((decision == 1 && healing.getManaRequirement() > manaActual)
            || (decision == 1 && lifeMax == lifeActual)
            || (decision == 2 && knockOut.getManaRequirement() > manaActual)
            || (decision == 3 && poisoning.getManaRequirement() > manaActual)) {
                continue;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        // cast the skill
        if(decision == 0) {
            castFireball(enemy);
        } else if (decision == 1) {
            castHealing();
        } else if (decision == 2) {
            castKnockOut(enemy);
        } else if (decision == 3) {
            castPoisoning(enemy);
        }
    }

    public void getStronger(double factor) {
        lifeMax *= factor;
        manaMax *= factor;
        manaMax += 3;
        powerMax += factor;

        lifeActual = lifeMax;
        manaActual = manaMax;
        powerActual = powerMax;

        isKnockedOut = false;
        isPoisoned[0] = 0;
        isPoisoned[1] = 0;
    }
}
```

*Skill.java*

```
public class Skill {
    private Being caster;
    private String name;
    private int level;
    private double value;
    private int manaRequirement;

    public Skill(Being caster, String name, int level, double value, int manaRequirement) {
        this.caster = caster;
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
        // means strength of the skill
        // multiplicated with level
        this.value = value;
        // also multiplicated with level
        this.manaRequirement = manaRequirement;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return (int)(caster.getPower() * value * level);
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public int getManaRequirement() {
        return manaRequirement * level;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have two more questions that I would like to have answered.

**Different languages**

Let's say I want to publish my program in different languages. Accordingly, all output statements would have to be adjusted. What methodologies exist for such a project?

**Graphic surface**

Suppose I want to plot all data graphically. I would have to rewrite all classes. Is there an effective way to separate the processing of the data from the output of the data?

Comment: Very nice to be able to test it online! But because the foes quit when they have no mana, it seems that just waiting and healing is the easiest strategy to win? Anyway nice project.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, it is very difficult to develop a complex game that is consistent and unwavering not only at the code level but also at the logic level. That's probably because it's my first attempts to program such games. But first get into the next round, when the enemy gets stronger, then that is not so easy with the trick: D

Comment: One other suggestion is tell the player how much mana, and what exactly the spell does, unless it's a deliberate choice? I like knowing beforehand what are my options and what those options cost/do.

Comment: Games (real world programs in general, really) are often not strict with OO design. You would do well to familiarize yourself with procedural approaches to problems, as well. Some developers argue that [OO is categorically bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM1iUe6IofM). Even if it isn't categorically bad, it is certainly not a magic solution to your problems, and you need to be able to recognize when you're creating bad infrastructure by trying to hard to use it.

Comment: Fun project :) Keep going.

Comment: [You might want to read this](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/) before continuing your design to avoid probably the most classical pitfall when starting to design RPGs. Not a big problem currently since you hardcode all different skills and actions, but it already goes in the direction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
// name stands for "useful functions"
public class UF {
```

Just call it `UsefulFunctions` then. You probably will find an even better name, if you think about what kind of helper functions this class contains, but never abbreviate a class name like that. And most importantly, never make it depend on a comment to be understandable.

More idiomatic names might be `HelperFunctions` or `UtilityFunctions`, even better if you add what they are for. You can also omit the `Functions`, since it is kind of obvious, and the class represents the thing which is a `Helper` or `Utility`. For Example `IOHelper`.

As statet by Timothy Truckle more explicitly in a comment, the Helpers do not need to be static, and it actually hurts your attempt of good object oriented design. This is what I wanted to imply by "the class represents the thing ...", which means you better treat them as objects with a certain behaviour. So the classes are more than just a set of functions. That whole class is actually your `Output`, not just some `UsefulFunctions`.

Your `Output` should abstract how and what exactly is being written out, and have an interface with methods like `printAllAliveBeingsStats(Collection<Being> beings)` (which comes close to what the first 8 lines of the main loops are doing) instead of the whole code being put into the `Game` class.

---

`NPC` might be idiomatic enough in the context of an RPG, but I would still recommend naming it `NonPlayerCharacter`, and derive it from a `Character`. I highly advise against deriving from `Being`, or even having anything named `Being`, because that could basically be anything, depending on the interpretation. Better call it `Creature`, if that is what you intended it to represent.

---

`Being` has a boolean field `alive`, and a method `isAlive()`, which returns the variable's value. The value is set once the `lifeActual` is set to 0. A better implementation of `isAlive()` would be to just `return lifeActual > 0`. This reduces the complexity of your code and reduces the risk of introducing hard to find bugs.

---

`alive` and `isKnockedOut` are inconsistent names. Often boolean variables are named with just the adjective (`alive` and `knockedOut`), because they are attributes of the object, while the methods returning them are named `isAlive` and `isKnockedOut` (which your's are already), because they are questions about the object's state.

---

`lifeActual` and the other actual variables are a bit confusing. What other lifes can there be? Metaphoric ones? Better call it `currentLife`, because it is the current state of the object. Also, `currentLife` reads more naturally than `lifeCurrent`. The latter even sounds like a noun.

---

You have a lot of getters and setters. This breaks encapsulation, and is not object oriented. It is just slightly better than accessing the fields directly. While in some cases they makes sense, it is not good practice to use them for every field. Objects should only expose the information about themselves that they need to.

For example, instead of allowing the `Skill` to access the caster's power level, add the power level to the constructor parameters of the skill and let the caster inject its power level. Since this is the only reason you inject the caster into the skill, you can even remove the knowledge about the caster from the skill class.

---

```
        if(command.equals("1")) {
            castFireball(enemy);
        } else if (command.equals("2")) {
            castHealing();
        } else if (command.equals("3")) {
            castKnockOut(enemy);
        } else if (command.equals("4")) {
            castPoisoning(enemy);
        } else if (command.equals("5")) {
            lifeActual = 0;
        }
```

This would look much clearer as a `switch` statement. Note that this did not work with strings before Java 7, but you should be over that.

```
        switch (command) {
            case "1":
                castFireball(enemy);
                break;
            case "2":
                castHealing();
                break:
            // and so on
        }
```

---

```
isPoisoned = new int[2];
```

How can you have an array of being poisoned? I don't quite understand what these 2 values represent, but if they are different things related to being poisoned, better use two variables. Also, `isSomething` implies a boolean value, so better not use it for int values.

---

```
        System.out.println("[1] Fireball");
        System.out.println("[2] Healing");
        System.out.println("[3] Knock Out");
        System.out.println("[4] Poisoning");
        System.out.println("[5] Give up");
        System.out.println("[*] Do nothing");
        System.out.print("Input: ");
```

This can be done clearer by concatenating the output and do one single println call. Don't forget to add newlines (\n).

```
        System.out.println("[1] Fireball\n"
                         + "[2] Healing\n"
                         + "[3] Knock Out\n"
                         // ...
                         + "[*] Do nothing\n");
```

The compiler will concatenate the strings during compile time, so no need to worry about performance of string concatenation.

---

`getStronger()` looks like a getter. `becomeStronger()` might be better.

---

```
while(player.getLife() > 0 && enemy.getLife() > 0) {
```

Here you could use the `isAlive()` method, and thus hide the details of how "being alive" is implemented.

---

You have the `int score` in the `Game` class. Shouldn't that be part of the `Player`? The Game can't score by killing NPCs, and neither can the NPCs score by killing the Player. So the score is an attribute of the Player.

---

```
public static void println(String text, int time) {
```

lies about what it does. It suggests that it does almost the same as `System.out.println`, just maybe on a different output than the command line. A better name might be `printAndwait(String text, int milliseconds)`.

---

Poisoning someone should not look like this: `enemy.isPoisoned();`. It looks like checking whether the enemy is currently poisoned or not. Better name it `player.setPoisoned(bool poisoned)`, or just `player.poison()`.

---

```
public static String displayGraphical(int value1, int value2, String symbol) {
```

What are these values? Better be more explicit with the parameter names. When calling the method, you should not need to read the method's body to know what parameters to pass. It should be obvious from the parameter names.

---

In `displayGraphical` of the class `UF` you use string concatenation a lot, in loops, and the method is called multiple times in the main loop. This is very inefficient, because every time you concatenate strings, a new string object is created, and after some time the old one will be deleted. Better use a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), for better performance and memory efficiency.

---

Coding in English as a non-native speaker, a translation error has found its way into your code: `Gratulation`. The English word is `Congratulations`. The risk of this happening can be reduced by reading all of the strings from a file, having one file for each language if you want to support multiple languages, and letting someone translate the file for you who does not need to be a programmer, because the "strings" are not part of the program anymore.

Comment: Also: there is no rule that a class providing common functionality must have static methods...

Comment: I agree and added a remark, as I wasn't explicit about it.

Comment: Can static methods really not be tolerated? I think otherwise sometimes the code looks a bit like "It had to be object-oriented without any ifs and buts". But some functionalities, if you think pragmatically, are just functions. Also the Java class library uses static methods, why can not I do that? And thanks for the other useful tips, they help me a lot! This code snippet will later be the basis for a large textual RPG.

Comment: You can use static methods, similar to the standard library, if you are writing a library. But inside of an object oriented program I recommend to avoid it. Note that the program does not automatically become more object oriented by replacing the static methods with calls to instance methods. It depends on the design of the class. As I suggested, you could replace the `UF` class with an `Output` class, which hides the details of outputting e. g. player stats. But it shouldn't just be a delegation to the `System.out.println` call. Let it handle all the outputs, and also the delays between them.

Comment: That sounds understandable, thank you for this tip. By the way: I find it amusing when two Germans talk to each other in English: D

Comment: `This can be done clearer by concatenating the output and do one single println call. Don't forget to add newlines`. I have to disagree. Your version might be as easy to read as the original (they're even formatted in such a way that the strings are in exactly the same spot), but the whole "don't forget to add newlines" really throws a wrench into that solution. So please replace the `\n` with the correct `System.lineSeparator()` calls and then check if you still think it's more readable.

Comment: _"A better implementation of isAlive() would be to just return lifeActual <= 0"_ This should be `lifeActual > 0`.

Comment: Another question: I know that i could use switch-statements, but I find them pretty ugly. You need more indents and for every sequence you should not forget a break-statement. This leads to more code and an additional error source. The language Python for example hasnt accept this language feature. I am just making my code more beautiful right now with the help of your and other tipps and thats why I am commenting so late :D

Answer (score 6):

The design needs overhaul. Specifically, the design of the `Skill` class (and concept)

Skills have properties and behaviors (=methods) that are related to the skill regardless of the caster.  for example, each skill can be either casted on an enemy or on the caster himself.  each skill has base power and mana consumption values, etc.  Your code needs to clearly represent the properties and behaviors that define a skill regardless of the caster.

You have in your game four *types* of Skills.  if you have a finite set of values of the same type, the best way to represent this is using `enum`.  So, if we make `Skill` class an `enum` and remove the reference to `Being`, the design reflects the concept of Skill in the best way.  For instance, initial values for the different skills are no longer defined in `Being`, but in `Skill`, the "name" property is redundant and I found a new attribute that is related to this type:

```
public enum Skill {

  FIREBALL(false, 1, 1).
  KNOCK_OUT(false, 0.5, 2).
  HEALING(true, 2, 3),
  POISONING(false, 0.2, 3);

  Skill(boolean castOnSelf, double value, int manaRequirement) {
     // assign to instance vars
  }

  private boolean castOnSelf;
  private double value;
  private int manaRequirement;
}
```

This design also greatly simplifies the code for deciding what to cast (hint: oyu can get to an enum instance from its String name using `valueOf()`)

now what about maxLevel? is it the same for all skill types or different?

Moving on: in your game, every `Being` has the same set of skills. that's fine. but every `Being` develops differently and this should be reflected by individual Skill instances together with the `Being` attributes that can modify a basic `Skill'

```
public class MySkill {
  private Skill skill;
  private int level;
  ...
```

So now, instead of individual variables, a `Being` has a `Set` of `MySkill` instances.  (this means that `MySkill` instances should be considered equal if they have same `skill`) This design allows for iteration over the skill set of one `Being` and of course, different `Being`s can easily have different skill sets.

Moving on: as I understand it, the formula for the effect of skill casting involves the base value of the skill, related to the skill only, the power of the being, related to the being only, and the level of player in that skill.  Perhaps in later version you will want to add defensive skills? also, in some RPG games, a random factor is added so that every skill casting can vary in effect. I would say that this complex logic merits its own `CastingEngine` that receives two `Being`s (attacker and target) and the skill that was chosen.  If the `CastingEngine` is an interface, you could write different engines that evolve in complexity.  the engine would apply all the above factors (including if the skill is casted on self....) and modify the `Being`s stats according to the outcome.

Answer (score 6):

I'll target one specific point: [magic numbers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)

```
public Game() {
    player = new Player("Player", 20, 5, 5);
    enemy = new NPC("Enemy", 20, 5, 5);
}
```

When you look at this code thirty years from now, or even a few months, will you remember what these numbers are? Sure, you can look at the class and see what input it takes, but specifically saying what they mean makes the code much easier to read.

Focus on readability first. Making your code easy to understand is the best way to make sure it gets finished and is easily maintained.

Look at how much easier this is to read and understand; it's almost like natural language.

```
public Game() {
    final int lifeMax = 20;
    final int manaMax = 5;
    final int powerMax = 5;

    player = new Player("Player", lifeMax, manaMax, powerMax );
    enemy = new NPC("Enemy", lifeMax, manaMax, powerMax );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answers already given, there's another problem with the Game class design.

First of all, the constructor creates the Player and NPC by itself, which leads to tight coupling: you could not replace any of the parameters used in creation of the Beings without changing the game class. Better: let the Game take its participants from the outside:

```
public Game(Player player, NPC enemy) {
    this.player = player;
    this.enemy = enemy;
}

...
in main:
    Player player = new Player("Player", 20, 5, 5);
    NPC enemy = new NPC("Enemy", 20, 5, 5);
    Game game = new Game(player, enemy);
    game.mainLoop();
```

Next step is: does the game really have to know who is a Player, and who is an NPC? You modeled both classes as being derieved from the common class Being, so maybe it should be possible to match any being vs any other? Without looking through the code en detail, you should strive for:

```
public class Game {
    private Being player1;
    private Being player2;

    ...

    public Game(Being player1, Being player2) {
        this.player1 = player1;
        this.player2 = player2;
    }
    ...
}
```